# How to do 1024-bit operations using arrays of uint64_t

Tags: c

I am trying to find a way to compute values that are of type `uint1024_t` (unsigned 1024-bit integer), by defining the 5 basic operations: plus, minus, times, divide, modulus.

The way that I can do that is by creating a structure that will have the following prototype:

```
typedef struct {
    uint64_t chunk[16];
} uint1024_t;
```

Now since it is complicated to wrap my head around such operations with `uint64_t` as block size, I have first written some code for manipulating `uint8_t`. Here is what I came up with:

```
#define UINT8_HI(x) (x >> 4)
#define UINT8_LO(x) (((1 << 4) - 1) & x)

void uint8_add(uint8_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t *res, int i) {
    uint8_t s0, s1, s2;

    uint8_t x = UINT8_LO(a) + UINT8_LO(b);
    s0 = UINT8_LO(x);

    x = UINT8_HI(a) + UINT8_HI(b) + UINT8_HI(x);
    s1 = UINT8_LO(x);
    s2 = UINT8_HI(x);

    uint8_t result = s0 + (s1 << 4);
    uint8_t carry = s2;
    res[1 + i] = result;
    res[0 + i] = carry;
}

void uint8_multiply(uint8_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t *res, int i) {
    uint8_t s0, s1, s2, s3;

    uint8_t x = UINT8_LO(a) * UINT8_LO(b);
    s0 = UINT8_LO(x);

    x = UINT8_HI(a) * UINT8_LO(b) + UINT8_HI(x);
    s1 = UINT8_LO(x);
    s2 = UINT8_HI(x);

    x = s1 + UINT8_LO(a) * UINT8_HI(b);
    s1 = UINT8_LO(x);

    x = s2 + UINT8_HI(a) * UINT8_HI(b) + UINT8_HI(x);
    s2 = UINT8_LO(x);
    s3 = UINT8_HI(x);

    uint8_t result = s1 << 4 | s0;
    uint8_t carry = s3 << 4 | s2;
    res[1 + i] = result;
    res[0 + i] = carry;
}
```

And it seems to work just fine, however I am unable to define the same operations for division, subtraction and modulus...

Furthermore I just can't seem to see how to implement the same principal to my custom `uint1024_t` structure even though it is pretty much identical with a few lines of code more to manage overflows.

I would really appreciate some help in implementing the 5 basic operations for my structure.

EDIT:

I have answered below with my implementation for resolving this problem.

Comment: This is a long-solved problem, and there are plenty of resources all over the Internet describing algorithms for arithmetic with non-standard bit-width integers. There are of course also a few libraries available for arbitrary precision arithmetic, unless your assignment is to implement it all yourself.

Comment: I do have to implement this myself, and I have not seen anything that could describe precisely what I am supposed to do on the internet. If you do have some websites to share, it will be much helpful

Comment: `gmp` is probably the most standard library for that. But there are plenty more. `BigInt`, etc.

Comment: https://github.com/vidursatija/CPL_1024bit_uint/blob/master/uint1024_t.c https://github.com/Lopa10ko/ITMO-programming-2021-2022/blob/main/clab2/clab2.c https://github.com/MariaMozgunova/uint1024_t

Comment: I've used gcrypt in the past for this sort of thing. It's fast and has lots of functions.

Comment: Vladouch, [Modular exponentiation without range restriction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/187257/29485) may be useful.

Comment: Refer to The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2 Chapter 4  - Arithmetic.

Comment: The name `uint1024_t` is unsuitable - the implementation is permitted to use that if it provides a 1024-bit type, so it is not available for user declaration.   See [section 7.20.1.1](https://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A665%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C-27%2C816%2Cnull%5D)

Comment: "After looking at the proposed answers I have written quite some code." --> You can answer you own question with your own answer below.

Comment: `uint64_sub()` should not be much different than `uint64_add()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with your implementation for `uint8_t` arrays:

- you did not parenthesize the macro arguments in the expansion. This is very error prone as it may cause unexpected operator precedence problems if the arguments are expressions. You should write:

  ```
  #define UINT8_HI(x) ((x) >> 4)
  #define UINT8_LO(x) (((1 << 4) - 1) & (x))
  ```
- storing the array elements with the most significant part first is counter intuitive. Multi-precision arithmetics usually represents the large values as arrays with the least significant part first.
- for a small type such as `uint8_t`, there is no need to split it into halves as larger types are available. Furthermore, you must propagate the carry from the previous addition. Here is a much simpler implementation for the addition:

  ```
  void uint8_add(uint8_t a, uint8_t b, uint8_t *res, int i) {
      uint16_t result = a + b + res[i + 0]; // add previous carry
      res[i + 0] = (uint8_t)result;
      res[i + 1] = (uint8_t)(result >> 8); // assuming res has at least i+1 elements and is initialized to 0
  }
  ```
- for the multiplication, you must add the result of multiplying each part of each number to the appropriately chosen parts of the result number, propagating the carry to the higher parts.

Division is more difficult to implement efficiently. I recommend you study an open source multi-precision package such as QuickJS' [libbf.c](https://github.com/bellard/quickjs/blob/master/libbf.c).

To transpose this to arrays of `uint64_t`, you can use unsigned 128-bit integer types if available on your platform (64-bit compilers gcc, clang and vsc all support such types).

Here is a simple implementation for the addition and multiplication:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NB_CHUNK  16

typedef __uint128_t uint128_t;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t chunk[NB_CHUNK];
} uint1024_t;

void uint0124_add(uint1024_t *dest, const uint1024_t *a, const uint1024_t *b) {
    uint128_t result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_CHUNK; i++) {
        result += (uint128_t)a->chunk[i] + b->chunk[i];
        dest->chunk[i] = (uint64_t)result;
        result >>= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uint64_t);
    }
}

void uint0124_multiply(uint1024_t *dest, const uint1024_t *a, const uint1024_t *b) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_CHUNK; i++)
        dest->chunk[i] = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_CHUNK; i++) {
        uint128_t result = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0, k = i; k < NB_CHUNK; j++, k++) {
            result += (uint128_t)a->chunk[i] * b->chunk[j] + dest->chunk[k];
            dest->chunk[k] = (uint64_t)result;
            result >>= CHAR_BIT * sizeof(uint64_t);
        }
    }
}
```

If 128-bit integers are not available, your 1024-bit type could be implemented as an array of 32-bit integers. Here is a flexible implementation with selectable types for the array elements and the intermediary result:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if 1  // if platform has 128 bit integers
typedef uint64_t type1;
typedef __uint128_t type2;
#else
typedef uint32_t type1;
typedef uint64_t type2;
#endif

#define TYPE1_BITS  (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(type1))
#define NB_CHUNK    (1024 / TYPE1_BITS)

typedef struct uint1024_t {
    type1 chunk[NB_CHUNK];
} uint1024_t;

void uint0124_add(uint1024_t *dest, const uint1024_t *a, const uint1024_t *b) {
    type2 result = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_CHUNK; i++) {
        result += (type2)a->chunk[i] + b->chunk[i];
        dest->chunk[i] = (type1)result;
        result >>= TYPE1_BITS;
    }
}

void uint0124_multiply(uint1024_t *dest, const uint1024_t *a, const uint1024_t *b) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_CHUNK; i++)
        dest->chunk[i] = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NB_CHUNK; i++) {
        type2 result = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0, k = i; k < NB_CHUNK; j++, k++) {
            result += (type2)a->chunk[i] * b->chunk[j] + dest->chunk[k];
            dest->chunk[k] = (type1)result;
            result >>= TYPE1_BITS;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I have said, my uint8_t is an EXAMPLE template that I can use directly with uint64_t to compute uint128_t, so the goal is to use only the uint8_t in my examples.  The two algorithms work perfectly, the only problem I am having is to actually apply them to a bigger structure

Comment: @Vladouch: if you intend to use `uint128_t` for your array of `uint64_t`, your `uint8_t` example is not a good approach: you should use the larger type for the intermediary result, not for the arguments. Can you post your addition and multiplication functions for arrays? The function `uint8_multiply` is only a small part of the multiplication problem.

Answer (score 2):

> find a way to compute ... the 5 basic operations: plus, minus, times, divide, modulus.

If `uint1024_t` used `uint32_t`, it would be easier.

I would recommend 1) half the width of the widest type `uintmax_t`, or 2) `unsigned`, whichever is smaller. E.g. 32-bit.

(Also consider something other than `uintN_t` to avoid collisions with future versions of C.)

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t chunk[1024/32];
} u1024;
```

Example of some untested code to give OP an idea of how using `uint32_t` simplifies the task.

```
void u1024_mult(u1024 *product, const u1024 *a, const u1024 *b) {
  memset(product, 0, sizeof product[0]);
  unsigned n = sizeof product->chunk / sizeof product->chunk[0];
  for (unsigned ai = 0; ai < n; ai++) {
    uint64_t acc = 0;
    uint32_t m = a->chunk[ai];
    for (unsigned bi = 0; ai + bi < n; bi++) {
      acc += (uint64_t) m * b->chunk[bi] + product->chunk[ai + bi];
      product->chunk[ai + bi] = (uint32_t) acc;
      acc >>= 32;
    }
  }
}
```

`+`, `-` are quite similar to the above.

`/`, `%` could be combined into one routine that computes the quotient and remainder together.

It is not that hard to post those functions here as it really is the **same as grade school math, but instead of base 10, base 2<sup>32</sup>**.  I am against posting it though as it is  fun exercise to do oneself.

I hope the `*` sample code above inspires rather than answers.

Comment: most non-MSVC compilers have `__int128`, and MSVC has `_udiv128`/`_umul128` so there won't be any problem using `uint64_t`

Comment: This is a possibility.  Yet as billions of processer per year in 2021 are embedded ones - many still with 8, 16, 32 cores, I have doubts that `__int128` is that universally available.  Even if 128 bit is at hand, crafting to the processor's native width can yield better performance.  IAC, I like to answer using standard C.

Comment: @phuclv, The C standard allows implementations to provide _any_ `uintN_t` (Section 7.20.1.1), so those identifiers are emphatically not available for user definition.

Comment: @TobySpeight who said anything about user-defined `uint64_t`?

Comment: I thought you did - you wrote "*there won't be any problem using `uint64_t`*" in reply to chux's "*consider something other than `uintN_t` to avoid collisions with future versions of C*".

Comment: After trying to run your code, and correcting minor mistakes, I can't get it to work. Is there anyway you can detail what exactly you wanted to do in it?

Comment: Good day, I have managed to get the addition, subtraction and multiplication to work, but I am struggling for the division, (The original post has been updated with the code). Could you please give me a clue to do the division and modulus? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vladouch A clue?  I [did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74654145/how-to-do-1024-bit-operations-using-arrays-of-uint64-t/74656120?noredirect=1#comment131773002_74654145).  IAC, div easier with access to a twice as wide type than used in `chunk[]`.

Comment: @Vladouch I still maintain using `uint32_t chunk[1024/32];` would simplify code and run faster - even though twice the iterations needed.  The individual iteration would be more than 2x fast as a `uint64_t` one.  Good luck.